# Static arrays are always filled with zeroes in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, arrays, broadcastreceiver, static-array

I would like to get values from some `static` `Array` inside `BroadcastReceiver`. The problem is that it is always filled with zeroes inside `BroadcastReceiver`, while it is not anywhere else in the application. Inside `MainActivity` I created a `testArray` method which also displays the same array into the logcat and the values are different.

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context k1, Intent k2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {
            Log.d("Receiver " + Integer.toString(i), Double.toString(Data.mean_temp_day[i]));
        }
    }

}
```

**What I get in logcat when onReceive is called**

```
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 0﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 1﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 2﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 3﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 4﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 5﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 6﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 7﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 8﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.007  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 9﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.017  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 10﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.017  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 11﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.027  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 12﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.027  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 13﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.027  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 14﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.027  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 15﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.027  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 16﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.027  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 17﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.027  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 18﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.027  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 19﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.037  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 20﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.037  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 21﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.037  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 22﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:03:02.037  10911-10911/com.example.nimboo:remote D/Receiver 23﹕ 0.0
```

**testArray method - part of MainActivity.java code**

```
public void testArray(View v) {
        for(int i=0; i<24; i++) {
            Log.d("Test " + Integer.toString(i), Double.toString(Data.mean_temp_day[i]));
        }
    }
```

**What I get in logcat when calling testArray**

```
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 0﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 1﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 2﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 3﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 4﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 5﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 6﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 7﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 8﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 9﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 10﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 11﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 12﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 13﹕ 24.721666666666664
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 14﹕ 12.02
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 15﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 16﹕ 0.0
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 17﹕ 21.323333333333334
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 18﹕ 22.481666666666666
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 19﹕ 22.06833333333333
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 20﹕ 22.098
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 21﹕ 21.98166666666667
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 22﹕ 21.67
01-17 22:02:23.387    9929-9929/com.example.nimboo D/Test 23﹕ 0.0
```

**Data.java**

```
public final class Data {
    public static double[] mean_temp_day = new double[24];
    private Data() {
    }
}
```

What is the reason of such results? I don't understand why does a `static` `Array` contain different values? How to get proper values of a `static` `Array` inside a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: How are you registering this receiver? If it is in the manifest as a `<receiver>` element, do you have an `android:process` attribute on that element? Also, bear in mind that your process may terminate at any point -- only use static data members as a cache, with data that can be lazy-initialized or otherwise obtained again.

Comment: Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml`, your are probably using a `process` attribute inside the receiver

Comment: I have a following line in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file: `<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />`

Comment: Due to the `android:process` entry in the manifest declaration for your `BroadcastReceiver`, it is running in a different process than your Activities. This is why you see the behaviour you are seeing (The process where the `BroadcastReceiver` is running has never had `Data` initalized). Remove the `android:process` specifier from the manifest for your `BroadcastReceiver`.